# How to align Radio Button and label in ionic3

Tags: ionic3

I am using the Ionic3 for developing an app
I want to create a Radio Button List. However, I need the radio button to appear on the left and the label(text) to be at the right Any ideas?

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-radio value="friends" checked></ion-radio>
  <ion-label>Public</ion-label>
</ion-item>

<ion-item>
  <ion-radio value="family"></ion-radio>
  <ion-label>Private</ion-label>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: just see ionic v1 sample https://codepen.io/edisonpappi/pen/jKOqYp

Answer (score 1):

You can use the item-left attribute in ion-radio

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-radio item-left></ion-radio>
    <ion-label>Option</ion-label>
</ion-item>
```

Answer (score 1):

In Ionic 5, use `slot="start"`

```html
<ion-item>
  <ion-radio slot="start"></ion-radio>
  <ion-label>Label</ion-label>
</ion-item>
```

If you want to radio button to appear right, use `slot="end"`.